# Do function types take precedence over argument types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type a redux action creator:

```js
const DO_SOMETHING = 'DO_SOMETHING'

interface DoSomethingAction extends Action<typeof DO_SOMETHING> {
  payload: number
}

const doSomething: ActionCreator<DoSomethingAction> = (n: number) => ({
  type: DO_SOMETHING,
  payload: n,
})
```

I had expected that calling this with `doSomething('why')` would fail, but it doesn't.

From what I understand, this is because the redux typings have:

```js
interface ActionCreator<A> {
  (...args: any[]): A
}
```

Why does `any` here take precedence over (or widen?) the `number` type in the argument list?

(see: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/en/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgeQPoGUEFkCiAVAEgSQDkBxGAXhgHJFUMcCTKAoJgSzCgFMAnAMwENgnGAEFgUVuADC3TvyghuAHhEA+GAG8mMGAAoAdIf7cA5hABcMfmACeAbQC6ASksimAXxbsufQcLES4ErY5Fa26lo6UDYADpyW2B5eHDwCQvAgKCAAtpxQABbsJgGSYDCcAB5cYAAmEKLipUrRcSC88MhoWHhExBHaMDH8NgA2IPw1lmAArtkARjxJTKCQsDWZOXmFYCaujdKy8opKcBu5BUUl4OoUumBTswvcTuTqupEwLfEdtN0MxAAaAZDUbjSYwMBA9xOFjrLLnbYmXSUADu+RslCcQA))

Comment: You're explicitly typing `doSomething` as function that gets any params (`const doSomething: ActionCreator<DoSomethingAction>`)

Comment: `const doSomething = (n: number) => ({ type: DO_SOMETHING, payload: n }) as const;` is probably what you're looking for, but not sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type annotations always take precedence over the type that could be inferred from the expression used to assign the variable or const. If you write an annotation then the expression is type-checked against it, if you don't write a type annotation then the expression is used to infer a type for the variable or const.

Function types are not special in this regard; consider this case:

```js
const foo: any = "hello";

function bar(x: number): void {}

bar(foo);
```

The type of `foo` is `any` because of the type annotation, not `string` because of the initialiser. So `bar` is callable with `foo` because `any` is assignable to `number`. Likewise, in your code the type of `doSomething` takes `...args: any[]` as its arguments because of the type annotation, not `number` because of the expression used to create the function.

This example, like yours, is unsound because the `any` type is unsound by design. If you want your code's type-safety to be checked by the compiler then you should not use `any`, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. ([my own summary](https://www.typescriptlang.org/en/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIgJ4DETIN4BQyyAFCAFzJyYCUlAbgPbAAmBAvgQaJLIigGUwUHPiKkKyAM7DQAczrImrDlwA2EMMhiNGyALwTKIAK4BbAEbRFylgYB8+TgQ1aLcKJSEjchnXuQAekDkBGoQRi0Ad0YoAGsXTWR3AC9KdGxfbV1iYOQY+KkAGmSTNzgWIA)). since the `ActionCreator` types come officially from the library -- would you advise not using those then?

Comment: If you want to call these functions from your own code (rather than pass them as callbacks) then you can use the more specific type that's inferred if you don't write a type annotation, and then you can still pass them as callbacks to the API since they will still be assignable to the less-specific function type that the API expects.